# When exactly did Brexit happen?

Tags: brexit

It's the day of Brexit and surely there are mixed feelings. But there's also mixed information when looking at countdowns about when it's going to happen *exactly*.

[This YouTube livestream](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DJEZr6ypnk0) counted down to 2020-02-01 00:00 CET (central european time, UTC+1), whereas [this website](https://daystobrexit.co.uk) <strike>counts down to 2020-02-01 00:00 GMT (UTC).</strike> counted down to 2020-02-01 00:00 UTC+2 for some reason.

Neither of those are authoritative sources, so which was it?

Comment: Related: https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/44426/exact-brexit-date-and-consequences (from when Brexit was going to be October/November 2019)

Comment: In 46 minutes time.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**11pm GMT on the 31st January, 2020.**

> *Brexit: UK to quit EU at 23:00 GMT, as PM promises 'new dawn'*
>
> <sub><sup>https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-politics-51315772</sup></sub>

Comment: There's also a live stream: https://www.bbc.com/news/live/uk-politics-51324431

Comment: @Fizz - I'm watching the livestream while eating British-produced nibbles and drinking a very nice [English vodka](https://www.blackcow.co.uk/)

Comment: 23:00 GMT is 0:00 CET

Answer (score 10):

Although technically the UK left the EU at the end of January, nothing much will change until the end of the transition period on 31st December 2020.

[What will change](https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-politics-51194363).

Between now and December we will find out what conditions the UK will agree to, to ensure smooth trade between themselves and the EU or US.

Comment: I am not sure how this answers the question, except that the exact timestamp of Brexit is quite irrelevant.

Comment: @Alexei I guess the point I am making is that in many ways, the ways in which Brexit might actually affect people in their everyday lives, Brexit hasn't happened yet.

Comment: @Jontia Brexit has happened regardless of if the effects have been felt or not.